# ASP.NET Deny Access to certain pages based on roles

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, web-config

I have the following in web.config, but still users without role MAnager or Admin can still access the pAccessData.aspx page.
The page is stored in directory Users

```
<location path="Users"  >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="~/Users/ChangePassword.aspx"  >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"  />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="~/Users/pAccessData.aspx"  >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Manager,Admin"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not add `<deny users="?"/>`, it should be like...

```
<location path="Users/pAccessData.aspx"  >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="Manager,Admin"/>            
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

**Edit:** you have specified `<allow users="*" />` which means, it will allow access to all users, as you have not mentioned the roles for which a user can access the folder.

```
<location path="Users"  >
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: All roles are allowed to access the folder. Its the page pAccessData that i want to restrict access to. Currently users without the roles MAnager, Admin are still able to access the page (which i do not want)

Comment: Can you just copy the settings from my answer and try ?

Comment: tried that. didn't work. All roles are allowed to access ChangePassword.aspx but only the Manager and Admin roles should be allowed to access pAccessData.aspx. Both pages are in the Users folder

Comment: Can you change this <allow roles="Manager,Admin"/> and split into <allow roles="Manager"/> <allow roles="Admin"/>

Comment: It should work, you may have folder hierarchy issue. These things I have used from many years and it is not a problem. you must have other problem. try to break down your problem and debug.

Comment: found the problem. There was another web.config file in the USERS directory that was overriding the settings in the root web.config

Comment: yah , it should override, but you not mention in the question that you are using multiple web.config :(

Comment: @daddyhaw, you should post your solution. That way you can choose it as the correct answer, and also get upvotes for it